# Laravel migration script produces multiple primary key columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

The following migration function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('table_name', 32);
        $table->string('column_name', 32);
        $table->integer('foreign_key', 11)->unsigned();
        $table->string('locale', 11);

        $table->text('value');

        $table->unique(['table_name', 'column_name', 'foreign_key', 'locale']);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

is producing the following SQL query:

```
create table `translations` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `table_name` varchar(32) not null, 
  `column_name` varchar(32) not null, 
  `foreign_key` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `locale` varchar(11) not null, 
  `value` text not null, 
  `created_at` timestamp null, 
  `updated_at` timestamp null
) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Notice the additional `auto_increment primary key` on the `foreign_key` field. This is the problem. How do I alter the migrations script so that it does not make `foreign_key` a second `auto_increment primary key` column?

(In case this looks familiar, this is from the base code for [Voyager](https://laravelvoyager.com/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the second argument of the `integer()` method is the step value used for the autoincrement. You can't set the length of a integer column, instead use the column type that better suits your needs.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns